# urlopen call with timeout not terminating after timeout

Tags: python, sockets, timeout, urllib2, urlopen

In Python 2.4.4, I'm using `urllib2.urlopen()` to request a resource. Before making the request, I'm setting a timeout with:

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
```

(This version of Python is too old to have a version of `urlopen()` with built-in timeout.)

In most cases, this appears to work fine. However, I have come across a server that just hangs on request. In Chrome, it takes nearly 5 minutes before the browser gives up and says:

> Google Chrome could not load the webpage because SERVERNAME took too long to respond. The website may be down, or you may be experiencing issues with your Internet connection.

In Python, the `urlopen` request seems to hang indefinitely, despite setting a short timeout. What exactly does `socket.setdefaulttimeout()` control, and is there a way to enforce a hard timeout on these connections (if 10 seconds go by, regardless of what else is happening, terminate the attempt)?

Answer (score 0):

```
def _reset_timeout(self, timeout=None):
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

def _set_timeout(self, timeout=None):
    if timeout:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)



default_timeout = socket.getdefaulttimeout()
try:
    self._set_timeout(timeout)
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

finally:
    self._reset_timeout(default_timeout)
```

socket has its own time out.  For every request you make, do set the timeout you want and then reset the timeout (in all cases including failures)

What might be happening is that in some cases, the server does not respond and the time out ends up longer than what you have set.

Here in the above code, we are getting the default timeout (whatever it is) and for our request we set it to whatever we want and then reset to whatever it was so that we do not change anything.

Comment: I am doing basically that in my code. The problem (and my question) is that even when setting a timeout in this way, I've run into cases where the call hangs indefinitely (long past the timeout value I set). I'm trying to figure out how this can be and if there's a way to ensure the call always fails as soon as the timeout value is reached.